# How to create AWS Admin User with Unconfirmed state

Tags: amazon-cognito

I am using AWS cognito API to create User in pool. User is being created successfully in Pool. 
Following is the code for that . But this code create user with FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD state but I want to create user in UNCONFIRMED state. Can someone help me on this?

```
AdminCreateUserRequest cognitoRequest =
        new AdminCreateUserRequest().withUserPoolId(id)
                .withUsername(r.getEmail())
                .withTemporaryPassword(r.getPassword().trim())
                .withUserAttributes(new AttributeType().withName(Constants.EMAIL).withValue(r.getEmail().trim()))
                .withUserAttributes(new AttributeType().withName(Constants.EMAI_VERIFIED).withValue("false"))
                .withUserAttributes(new AttributeType().withName(Constants.GIVEN_NAME).withValue(r.getFirstName().trim()))
                .withUserAttributes(new AttributeType().withName(Constants.FAMILY_NAME).withValue(r.getLastName().trim()));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change User Status FORCE\_CHANGE\_PASSWORD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40287012/how-to-change-user-status-force-change-password)

Comment: I think you might have to call `adminSetUserPassword` with the permanent flag (as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56948249/3486675), but there are some other solutions in the linked question above too. The `adminCreateUser` [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminCreateUser.html) say "In either case, the user will be in the FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD state until they sign in and change their password," so I don't think it would be possible to do this all with only one API call.

Comment: is it true, boto3.client('cognito-idp') works different , because when I am using this py script then it creating user in UNCONFIRMED  and I am expecting same behavior with java api.

Comment: Sounds like it, but you can check in the source code.

Comment: I think AWS is not bias in terms of technology, it feature that AWS support for all tech clients.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SignUpRequest to create user with **unconfirmed** status

```
SignUpRequest request = new SignUpRequest().withClientId(clientId)
                .withUsername(userSignUpRequest.getUsername()).withPassword(userSignUpRequest.getPassword())
                .withUserAttributes(emailAttr, groupAttr);
        return cognitoClient.signUp(request)
```

After signup, user will get code on the email mentioned during signup.You can confirm user signup using different request taking code from user as input.