# Getting 503 error when calling aws cognito-idp initiate-auth

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm currently trying to run `aws cognito-idp initiate-auth`, I'm using the correct username, password and client id, so I'm not sure what to do.

[This is the error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2oOB.png)

Comment: Nothing seems wrong with your command. Is it possible that the service was actually temporarily unavailable (503)?

Comment: I've used this service before to authenticate my aws Cognito account

Comment: If the service is actually temporarily unavailable, how do I change my account status from FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD? @RegisterSole

Comment: Maybe try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40287012/how-to-change-user-status-force-change-password

Comment: I did what they recommended and this is what I'm getting https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iLEksxx02utQmxNS_IH0nzVaCFUTEXzN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Is there a mismatched double quote or quote in one of the masked fields? dquote seems to indicate so

Comment: The only quote marks that exist in the command are around the password attribute which is in double quotes

Comment: Ok, is there a special character in the password, like one of these `#\`$"\!'`? If yes, can you try again, but replace the double quotes with single quotes? Double quotes may not escape these characters in UNIX.

Comment: I have a special character in my password and I'm now using single quotes. I'm getting An error occurred (503) when calling the InitiateAuth operation: Service Unavailable